# how to get access to error message from abort command when using custom error handler

Tags: python, http, flask, http-error

Using a python flask server, I want to be able to throw an http error response with the abort command and use a custom response string and a custom message in the body

```
@app.errorhandler(400)
def custom400(error):
    response = jsonify({'message': error.message})
    response.status_code = 404
    response.status = 'error.Bad Request'
    return response

abort(400,'{"message":"custom error message to appear in body"}')
```

But the error.message variable comes up as an empty string.  I can't seem to find documentation on how to get access to the second variable of the abort function with a custom error handler

Comment: Is `error.description` what you're looking for?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

If you look at [`flask/__init__.py`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/d517f35d60a14fcea2e503f578e65b68eafa6577/flask/__init__.py#L17) you will see that `abort` is actually imported from [`werkzeug.exceptions`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/5eed9385b861a1ae53c03eaae5a8dea4480113d6/werkzeug/exceptions.py#L602).  Looking at the [`Aborter` class](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/5eed9385b861a1ae53c03eaae5a8dea4480113d6/werkzeug/exceptions.py#L578-600), we can see that when called with a numeric code, the particular `HTTPException` subclass is looked up and called with all of the arguments provided to the `Aborter` instance.  Looking at [`HTTPException`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/5eed9385b861a1ae53c03eaae5a8dea4480113d6/werkzeug/exceptions.py#L74-160), paying particular attention to [lines 85-89](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/5eed9385b861a1ae53c03eaae5a8dea4480113d6/werkzeug/exceptions.py#L85-89) we can see that the second argument passed to `HTTPException.__init__` is stored in the `description` property, as @dirn pointed out.

You can either access the message from the `description` property:

```
@app.errorhandler(400)
def custom400(error):
    response = jsonify({'message': error.description['message']})
    # etc.

abort(400, {'message': 'custom error message to appear in body'})
```

or just pass the description in by itself:

```
@app.errorhandler(400)
def custom400(error):
    response = jsonify({'message': error.description})
    # etc.

abort(400, 'custom error message to appear in body')
```

Comment: This is a great way to extend abort's functionality with custom error messages. Thank you for this

Comment: Is there a way to do this with every status code instead of having to write a custom error handler for each code? Ex: `abort(409, 'There was a time conflict')`, `abort(400, 'custom error message to appear in body')`

Comment: Duplicate answer -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45412576/853167

Answer (score 75):

People rely on `abort()` too much. The truth is that there are much better ways to handle errors.

For example, you can write this helper function:

```
def bad_request(message):
    response = jsonify({'message': message})
    response.status_code = 400
    return response
```

Then from your view function you can return an error with:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    if error_condition:
        return bad_request('message that appears in body')
```

If the error occurs deeper in your call stack in a place where returning a response isn't possible then you can use a custom exception. For example:

```
class BadRequestError(ValueError):
    pass

@app.errorhandler(BadRequestError)
def bad_request_handler(error):
    return bad_request(str(error))
```

Then in the function that needs to issue the error you just raise the exception:

```
def some_function():
    if error_condition:
        raise BadRequestError('message that appears in the body')
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: is it preferable (faster) to `return bad_request(...)` directly when you can rather than just `raise BadRequestError(...)` ?

Comment: You can raise abort anywhere when you want, no need to return.

Comment: How is this any better? When not done from a view (and you need to register the error handler), the only difference is that you call `raise BadRequestError` instead of `abort`, with the added complication of having to register a custom exception.

Answer (score 43):

I simply do it like this:

```
    abort(400, description="Required parameter is missing")
```

Comment: The best answer in my opinion.

Comment: When you want to return a json type response. You need make_response.

Comment: To clarify Minh's comment from Jul 7, in `Werkzeug>=1.0.1` the code in this answer will generate a proper JSON response. I was even able to pass a `dict` as description and Werkzeug correctly generated a nested JSON response.

Comment: Unfortunately this returns HTML I do not want. I just want the message to print ONLY. Here is what curl output looks like:

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>Required parameter is missing</p>`

Answer (score 10):

`flask.abort` also accepts `flask.Response`

```
abort(make_response(jsonify(message="Error message"), 400))
```

Comment: You even not need to using jsonify:
abort(make_response({'message': 'Error message'}, 400))