# Flask - custom error messages on abort

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I'd like to be able to display custom error messages using abort() in Flask. I have run into an unusual situation that I am having trouble with. My code is below.

```
from flask import Flask, abort, jsonify, make_response, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.errorhandler(400)
def custom400(error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'message': error.description}), 400)

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    abort(400, 'custom error message')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The code above works but behaves differently if I attempt to access any form data because I lose access to the custom error message.

```
def test():
    a = request.form['some_value']
    abort(400, 'custom error message')
```

How can I avoid this situation? Is this a Flask bug?

Note: The code above was taken from [how to get access to error message from abort command when using custom error handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294889/how-to-get-access-to-error-message-from-abort-command-when-using-custom-error-ha)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I lose access to the custom error message"?

Comment: I'm almost certain that the error doesn't have a description because you aren't setting `some_value` in your POST body so the 400 error comes from `request.form.__getitem__` - what happens if you change the first line of `test` to `a = request.form.get('some_value')`?

Comment: @SeanVieira - You are right! I had no idea that my attempt to access an invalid dictionary object resulted in a 400. Could you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You can pass a message with the error code like `abort(404, "my custom error message")` and flask will return a simple error page with an `<h1>` containing the canonical name for that error code, and then your custom text in a `<p>` tag below that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error doesn't have a description because you aren't setting `some_value` in your POST body so the 400 error comes from `request.form.__getitem__` - change the first line of test to `a = request.form.get('some_value')` and your `abort` error will be thrown instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to render a template together with the error message, you can define the error handler

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    error=['Page Not Found','Oops']
    return render_template('errors.html', error=error), 404
```

To use, raise the error by

```
abort(404)
```

Make sure to import abort

```
from flask import abort
```

Then you can access the error message list in jinja

Comment: Those using the stock error mechanisms can simply pass in an additional argument `abort(404,"I don't know what you're up to there but it ain't right")`