# python swagger + flask abort returned empty error message

Tags: python, swagger

so, i'm trying to use custom abort message while using SwaggerClient. when using flask restful abort function, i can see the abort message on the SwaggerUI. but when i'm trying to see the error message while using the python module, im getting bravado.exception error code.
i tried to use @namespace.response decorator, i tried to use `"also_return_response": True, "disable_fallback_results": True` and still, no hope.
i would love to get some help/hints etc..

some of my code:

```
_api = Api(_app, version='1.0', title=self.name, description=self.name, errors = errors, )


NAMESPACE = "test"
namespace = _api.namespace(NAMESPACE, description=NAMESPACE)

@namespace.route("/error")
class SystemStatus(Resource):
    @namespace.doc("status")
    # @namespace.response(409, "Missing Parameter")
    def get(self):
        _api.abort(409, "testError")
```

and the usage of the SwaggerCLient:

```
def testing2(self):
        print("In testing2")
        return self.swagger_client.test.status().response()
```

Error for example: `bravado.exception.HTTPConflict: 409 CONFLICT: Response specification matching http status_code 409 not found for operation Operation(status). Either add a response specification for the status_code or use a 'default' response.`

and the UI: [SwaggerUIResponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYup8.png)

Comment: You might get more helpful responses if you post some code.

Comment: @moeassal added to your request

Comment: try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294889/how-to-get-access-to-error-message-from-abort-command-when-using-custom-error-ha