# Generic Flask Error Handler for HTTP Status Code 413

Tags: python, flask, file-upload, http-status-code-413

I'm writing an error handler for the `RequestEntityTooLarge` exception in Flask such that the exception can be caught when it's raised in any views. I'd like to handle the exception by flashing a message on top of the page where it's raised.

Below is what I have so far, is there a way I can get the view where the exception is raised so I can re-render it?

```
@app.errorhandler(413)
def request_entity_too_large(error):
    flash("File too large", "error-box")
    return render_template(...) // it should re-render the view where exception is raised
```

Since Flask throws this exception automatically, I think try/catch blocks with custom exception class can be helpful here, I'm curious if there're other easier way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw the exception using the `abort` function.

```
from flask import abort

@app.route('/something')
def something():
    if (error_occur):
        abort(413)
    else:
        something_else()


@app.errorhandler(413)
def custom_error(error):
    return render_template('413.html'), 413
```

Inside your HTML template file, you can display that `flash` message.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but this is not what I'm looking for. I'm not using a custom error page. I need the '413.html' to be a variable so it can render the same view where abort(413) is called, and abort(413) will be called in different views. I ended up using a try/except block and error.description to achieve what I wanted from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294889/how-to-get-access-to-error-message-from-abort-command-when-using-custom-error-ha)